# FFmpeg per frame metadata with RTSP and H264

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, h.264, rtsp, libavformat

How can one send per frame metadata with FFmpeg over an RTSP stream using H264 encoded video?

I need to send per-frame metadata from an application that streams video from a camera to another application via RTSP using ffmpeg and ffserver.

I have tried `AVFrame::metadata` using `av_dict_set` before trying to write the frame but the receiver does not see the metadata: `av_dict_count(DecodedFrame->metadata)` returns 0. 
If this is the correct approach, when should I call `av_dict_set`, I am currently calling it before `avcodec_encode_video2()`

I have also tried setting the `AVPacket::side_data` but again the reader does not see this: `pkt.side_data_elems` is 0 at the reader. I am doing this before calling `av_interleaved_write_frame()`.

Any help or suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you found the way to resolve this?

Comment: @superware No unfortunately not. My current implementation streams image metadata on a different UDP socket and I have no logic to associate the metadata with a specific frame. This is not a big issue but it does have some unwanted side effects.